# Shellexecute Return Value error messages

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I'm getting the return value when I call ShellExecute - an integer. Where can I get the associated error messages? I know they're general, but I've seen messages in the MS documentation.

Comment: Take them from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: ...as [MS itself does](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918/en)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error handling for `ShellExecute` is something of a disaster. Raymond Chen discusses it here: [Why does ShellExecute return SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED for nearly everything?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121018-00/?p=6303) So, even if you can convert the handful of possible `ShellExecute` errors into text, you'll find that you invariably get `Access denied`. And that's not very helpful.

The bottom line is that if you want real error reporting then you need to use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx). If that fails you call `GetLastError` to get the Win32 error. To turn it into an exception with the descriptive text, call `RaiseLastOSError`. If you just want the descriptive text associated with an error, you call `SysErrorMessage`.